# Getting the day of a date

Tags: vb.net, date

I have a series of dates formatted as:

26/03/1992
12/06/2010
13/01/1995

etc... it's in DD/MM/YYYY. I need to find the day like "Tuesday", "Monday" etc out of them.

I know I need to parse the date or something but I'm unsure how to go about this.

Comment: Bravo for a famous question as your first question!

Comment: 39k views and just **3** votes. +1 for helping me find a solution

Answer (score 8):

You can cast it as a DateTime and use the DayOfWeek property which returns a DayOfWeek enumerator.

Not sure in VB.NET but in C# it's like

```
DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek or DateTime.Parse(theDateString).DayOfWeek
```

Comment: In VB.NET it's... the same ;-)

Comment: This gave me the actuall date like 24th 25th of the day instead of like Monday, Tuesday

Comment: @CostasAletrari - `DateTime.Now.Day` would give you 24, 25 etc. `DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek` gives you the name of the day. See msdn documentation for clarification: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5):

You want to look at the format strings for the [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tostring(VS.71).aspx) method. `MyDate.ToString("dddd")` will get you what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime.Parse("2010/12/31").dayofweek
```

Answer (score 2):

The best thing it works for me in vb 2010 is

I add timer and enabled it then i put it like that

```
Label6.Text = Format(Now, "dddd/dd")
```

`"dd"` gives me the day Num.
`"dddd"` gives me the name of the day

Comment: How to make it like thursday = 05, not just 5? Can I do this without using condition?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the date into a date datatype, then use the format function. This displays monday:

```
Dim d As Date
d = "11/23/2009"
MsgBox(Format(d, "dddd"))
```

You could also get a numeric day of the week using d.DayOfWeek.

Answer (score 1):

```
'Declaration
<SerializableAttribute> _
<ComVisibleAttribute(True)> _
Public Class ArgumentOutOfRangeException
    Inherits ArgumentException
    Implements ISerializable
'Usage
Dim instance As ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek.aspx) of the DateTime members Parse, TryParse, DayOfWeek and ToString.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
dateValue.DayOfWeek.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

In VB try this:

```
DateTimePicker1.Value.DayOfWeek.ToString
```

It works

Answer (score -2):

```
MsgBox(Now.Date.DayOfWeek.ToString)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately I don't believe this answers the question of how to parse date strings